# Free space not reclaimed after online resizing ext4 in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext4

My root partition was filling up, with only 500 mbs left, I wanted to resize my root partition from 20 Gb to 40Gb

So I resized my partition by using these steps:

1. Using Gparted to resize another partition to give space for the EXT4
2. Using fdisk, deleting the root partition (on /dev/sda2), and creating it again using the new size
3. resize2fs /dev/sda2
4. Updating grub2

But now the problem is that although I can boot in my new partition and the new partition shows it is 40Gb, but the free size was still 500mb. So I booted from a LiveCD and checked with e2fsck -p /dev/sda2, it reported clean. So I added the -f flag (force check), still, the drive is full.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` please.

Comment: and add the filesystem size info from `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2`

Comment: thanks, but I used gparted to check partition and it just fixed it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gparted under livecd to check partition and it just fixed it for me.

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer by marking it as such, if this fixed your problem.